# Semantic Once for KafkaProducer in Apache Flink Cause low rate of produce

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

When we use semantic once option in our kafka producer in flink, while checkpointing is enabled, we'll face low rate of producement and also our lag for kafka topic which we are consuming increase.

Is there any parameters to tune kafka producement & consumer lag?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, your downstream consumers that are configured with `isolation.level` set to `read_committed` will experience latency that is tied to the checkpoint interval. This happens because the `FlinkKafkaProducer` is only committing transactions as a part of completing each checkpoint.

So you'll want to reduce the checkpointing interval. For more on configuring Flink to work with Kafka transactions, see the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-producers-and-fault-tolerance).